# How to register custom object formatter for th:data-* fields in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to register a custom formatter `AddressConverter`. So that every address that I show in the frontend is automatically formatted in a certain way (zip + town).

It works in general for `th:text` fields, but not if I'm passing values via `th:data-*` attribute.

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {
     @ModelAttribute("example")
     public Address example() {
         return new Address("12345", "town");
     }
}

public class AddressConverter implements org.springframework.format.Formatter<Address> {
    @Override
    public Address parse(String address, Locale locale) {
        String[] split = address.split(",");
        return new Address(split[0], split[1]);
    }

    @Override
    public String print(Address address, Locale locale) {
        return address.getZip() + "," + address.getTown();
    }
}

class Address {
    String zip, town;
    public Address(String zip, String town) {
          this.zip = zip;
          this.town = town;
    }
}


@Configuration
public class MainConfig {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatter(addressConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public AddressConverter addressConverter() {
        return new AddressConverter();
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<div th:text="${example?.address}" />
<div th:text="${{example?.address}}" />
<div th:data-example="${{example?.address}}"/>
```

Printed result:

```
org.example.Address@11c26b5
12345,town
org.example.Address@11c26b5
```

While actually the `th:data-example` field is not directly printed, but rendering can be inspected with chrome developer tools.

So how can I make it work on `data-*` fields?

Comment: I failed to reproduce your example. With Spring Boot in version `2.2.2.RELEASE` it worked as intended. Could it be dependency issue? (e.g. you're using thymeleaf `2.1` instead of `3.0`)